# android - ScrollView doesn't scroll when keyboard is up

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml, android-scrollview

I have the following xml file in Android Studio:

activity_register.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/register"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:context="mk.klikniobrok.klikniobrok.RegisterActivity">

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/ScrollView01"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingBottom="48dp">


        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/content"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/layout_top_margin"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/input"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:orientation="vertical">


                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/name"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="@string/name_hint"
                    android:inputType="text"
                    android:paddingBottom="8dp"
                    android:paddingTop="8dp"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/input_text_size" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/username"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="@string/user_hint"
                    android:inputType="text"
                    android:paddingBottom="8dp"
                    android:paddingTop="8dp"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/input_text_size" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/password"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="@string/pass_hint"
                    android:inputType="textPassword"
                    android:paddingBottom="8dp"
                    android:paddingTop="8dp"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/input_text_size" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/repeatPwd"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="@string/repeatPwd_hint"
                    android:inputType="textPassword"
                    android:paddingBottom="8dp"
                    android:paddingTop="8dp"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/input_text_size" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/email"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="@string/email_hint"
                    android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                    android:paddingBottom="8dp"
                    android:paddingTop="8dp"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/input_text_size" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/phone"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="@string/phone_hint"
                    android:inputType="phone"
                    android:paddingBottom="8dp"
                    android:paddingTop="8dp"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/input_text_size" />

            </LinearLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/footer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:gravity="end"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingBottom="2dp"
        android:paddingLeft="8dp"
        android:paddingRight="8dp"
        android:paddingTop="2dp">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/registerButton"
            style="@style/RobotoBoldButtonStyle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/ripple_transparent"
            android:text="РЕГИСТРИРАЈ СЕ"
            android:textSize="16sp" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

When the keyboard is not up I can see every element but whenever the keyboard comes up the ScrollView does not scroll down to reveal the covered elements. I have read through StackOverflow and added android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize" to the AndroidManifest.xml but it still does not work.

What happens to be the problem and how can I fix it?

Comment: I have just tried your layout in a test project. It scrolls for me, even without `adjustResize`. Can you try on another device or emulator? Are you by any chance suspended in the debugger?

Comment: @MarcinKoziński I tried it on 3 devices, two pre-Lollipop and one running vanilla Android M, it works only on 1. This is weird.

Comment: Try to remove the RelativeLayout inside the ScrollView. It is not necessary, although it should work with it also.

Answer (score 1):

Please try to set `android:layout_height="match_parent"` on the root element.

Your root element has `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` (calculate your height based on your children) and it's main child has `android:layout_height="match_parent"` (calculate your height based on your parent). It looks like chicken and egg problem and I suppose that's why it works on some devices and on some others it doesn't.

To be honest, I haven't tried if this works, but that's what I concluded. If it doesn't help, I'll give it another look.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed, the problem was using top margin in the LinearLayout instead of padding for the elements, apparently this is a problem.